# How do I fix Synaptic Weights error for Python 3.9.1?

Tags: python, neural-network

Here I have tried to create a simple neural network in Python importing the numpy module. class NeuralNetwork was defined with a random seed and synaptic weights.

```
import numpy as np

class NeuralNetwork():

    def _init_(self):
        np.random.seed(1)

        self.synaptic_weights = 2 * random.random((3, 1)) - 1

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + exp(-x))

    def sigmoid_derivative(self, x):
        return x * (1 - x)

    def train(self, training_inputs, training_outputs, training_iterations):

        for iteration in range(training_iterations):

            output = self.think(training_inputs)
            error = training_outputs - output
            adjustments = dot(training_inputs.T, error * self.sigmoid_derivative(output))
            self.synaptic_weights += adjustments

    def think(self, inputs):

        inputs = inputs.astype(float)
        output = self.sigmoid(np.dot(inputs, self.synaptic_weights))

        return output


if __name__ == "__main__":

    neural_network = NeuralNetwork()

    print('Random synaptic weights: ')
    print(NeuralNetwork.synaptic_weights)

    training_inputs = np.array([[0,0,1],
                                [1,1,1],
                                [1,0,1],
                                [0,1,1]])

    training_outputs = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T

    neural_network.train(training_inputs, training_outputs, 1000)

    print('Synaptic weights after training: ')

    print(neural_network.synaptic_weights)

    G = str(input('input 1: '))
    g = str(input('input 2: '))
    O = str(input('input 3: '))

    print('New situation: input data = ', G, g, O)
    print('Output data: ')
    print(neural_network.think(np.array([G, g, O])))
```

I keep getting an Attribute error, even though I am using numpy and have the NeuralNet defined with synaptic_weights.

```
Random synaptic weights: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python 3.9\neural_net.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(NeuralNetwork.synaptic_weights)
AttributeError: class NeuralNetwork has no attribute 'synaptic_weights'
[Finished in 0.465s]
```

Comment: You have written `_init_` instead of `__init__`, so that code doesn't run when the instance is created.

Comment: Okay thank you for your input, sometimes the underscores get confusing when it continues the line. Since you were the first to respond, would you like to join my team? It is a new team so you will be the first to join!

Comment: I did that and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: The first time around, you are asking for the weights from the class, rather than the instance. Another typo.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few errors.

`__init__` and  `Neural_Network.synaptic_weights` - > `neural_network.synaptic_weights`.

The below should fix them.

```
import numpy as np


class NeuralNetwork():

    def __init__(self):
        np.random.seed(1)

        self.synaptic_weights = 2 * np.random.random((3, 1)) - 1

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

    def sigmoid_derivative(self, x):
        return x * (1 - x)

    def train(self, training_inputs, training_outputs, training_iterations):

        for iteration in range(training_iterations):

            output = self.think(training_inputs)
            error = training_outputs - output
            adjustments = np.dot(training_inputs.T, error * self.sigmoid_derivative(output))
            self.synaptic_weights += adjustments

    def think(self, inputs):

        inputs = inputs.astype(float)
        output = self.sigmoid(np.dot(inputs, self.synaptic_weights))

        return output


if __name__ == "__main__":

    neural_network = NeuralNetwork()

    print('Random synaptic weights: ')
    print(neural_network.synaptic_weights)

    training_inputs = np.array([[0,0,1],
                                [1,1,1],
                                [1,0,1],
                                [0,1,1]])

    training_outputs = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T

    neural_network.train(training_inputs, training_outputs, 1000)

    print('Synaptic weights after training: ')

    print(neural_network.synaptic_weights)

    G = str(input('input 1: '))
    g = str(input('input 2: '))
    O = str(input('input 3: '))

    print('New situation: input data = ', G, g, O)
    print('Output data: ')
    print(neural_network.think(np.array([G, g, O])))
```